# Detect an SslStream (client) connection attempt to an insecure Server (NetworkStream)?

Tags: c#, ssl, tcpclient, networkstream

I have a server that is listening for clients with a `TcpListener.BeginAcceptTcpClient()` method.  When a client connects, the `EndAcceptTcpClient` method gives me the `TcpClient` object and then I call that client stream's `NetworkStream.BeginRead()` to listen for data transmitted from the client.

Everything works well until a client (who is expecting the server to support SSL) attempts to connect to the (insecure) server.  The data that is retrieved from the `NetworkStream.BeginRead()` callback when the client attempts to do the SSL handshaking, is gibberish of course, but what is the proper way to detect this handshake after reading the data vs a "normal" message from a client?

Does an SSL handshake have a known header/signature identifier that I could check for by looking at the first few bytes of received messages to distiguish the difference between a normal message and the SSL handshake?  From inspection the bytes received, it looks like it may be ASCII `0x16 0x03 0x01 0x00` (a.k.a `<SYN><ETX><SOH><NUL>`).

If there is a known header, is there a response I can send to the client to tell it the authentication failed (via the NetworkStream)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found some information about the SSL protocol (refs [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3897883/how-to-detect-an-incoming-ssl-https-handshake-ssl-wire-format), [2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur%2Fgtps5%2Fs5rcd.html)) and there is a standard header that I can look for:

From the IBM reference site [2](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/tpfhelp/current/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.ztpf-ztpfdf.doc_put.cur%2Fgtps5%2Fs5rcd.html):

```
Byte   0       = SSL record type = 22 (SSL3_RT_HANDSHAKE)
Bytes 1-2      = SSL version (major/minor)
Bytes 3-4      = Length of data in the record (excluding the header itself).
Byte   5       = Handshake type
Bytes 6-8      = Length of data to follow in this record
Bytes 9-n      = Command-specific data
```

So I can look for a message beginning with `0x16 [0x?? 0x??] [0x?? 0x??] 0x01` (the SSL "Client Hello" message).

For the rejection message, it looks like I can send `0x15 0x?? 0x?? 0x00 0x02 0x02 0x28` which is translated to `<NACK>`, (2byte version), this is a 2 byte long message, fatal alert, "handshake failed" [3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security).

Answer (score 0):

An SSL/TLS client will initiate a handshake by sending a [Client Hello](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-7.4.1.2) message.

In XDR notation, this is:

```
  struct {
      ProtocolVersion client_version;
      Random random;
      SessionID session_id;
      CipherSuite cipher_suites<2..2^16-2>;
      CompressionMethod compression_methods<1..2^8-1>;
      select (extensions_present) {
          case false:
              struct {};
          case true:
              Extension extensions<0..2^16-1>;
      };
  } ClientHello;
```

Here, what you're seeing is before that: it's the [record layer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5246#section-6.2), for a handshake message (`0x16`) with protocol TLS 1.0 (`0x0301`). It should be followed by a length and then `0x01` for a "Client Hello" and a version again (possibly different: the highest supported by the client).

From a practical point of view, it's worth looking at actual packets (e.g. on HTTPS) using Wireshark. There are some sample captures and example [on this page](http://wiki.wireshark.org/SSL) (although you won't need to decipher the traffic for what you're trying to do).